# Unexpected ref object provided for div. Use either a ref-setter function or React.createRef(). How can i solve it?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i created responsive mobile menu with tailwind css in react js project. All code works fine. There's no error in my code. When i use in rendeaning ref it gives me a waring in console. "Unexpected ref object provided for div. Use either a ref-setter function or React.createRef()." How can i solve it?

[*https://i.ibb.co/PG0xFwn/Screenshot-2022-05-01-at-3-43-35-PM.png*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YEJT1.png)

```js
<Transition
        show={isOpen}
        enter="transition ease-out duration-100 transform"
        enterFrom="opacity-0 scale-95"
        enterTo="opacity-100 scale-100"
        leave="transition ease-in duration-75 transform"
        leaveFrom="opacity-100 scale-100"
        leaveTo="opacity-0 scale-95"
      >
        {(ref) => (
          <div className="lg:hidden" id="mobile-menu">
            <div ref={ref} className="px-2 pt-2 pb-3 space-y-1 sm:px-3">
              <CustomLink
                to="/"
                className=" hover:bg-red-700 text-white block px-3 py-2 rounded-md text-base font-medium"
              >
                Home
              </CustomLink>

              <CustomLink
                to="/manage"
                className="text-gray-300 hover:bg-red-700 hover:text-white block px-3 py-2 rounded-md text-base font-medium "
              >
                Manage Inventories
              </CustomLink>

              {user && (
                <>
                  <CustomLink
                    to="/addInventory"
                    className="text-gray-300 hover:bg-red-700 hover:text-white block px-3 py-2 rounded-md text-base font-medium"
                  >
                    Add Item
                  </CustomLink>

                  <CustomLink
                    to="/myItem"
                    className="text-gray-300 hover:bg-red-700 hover:text-white block px-3 py-2 rounded-md text-base font-medium"
                  >
                    My Items
                  </CustomLink>
                </>
              )}

              <CustomLink
                to="/blog"
                className="text-gray-300 hover:bg-red-700 hover:text-white block px-3 py-2 rounded-md text-base font-medium"
              >
                Blog
              </CustomLink>
              {user ? (
                <button
                  onClick={logOut}
                  className="border-2 bg-red-700 hover:bg-indigo-700 hover:border-white-700 px-4 py-1 text-white rounded-sm transition-all duration-300 ease-in-out focus:shadow-outline focus:outline-none"
                >
                  Logout
                </button>
              ) : (
                <button
                  onClick={() => navigate("/login")}
                  className="border-2 hover:bg-red-700 hover:border-red-700 px-4 py-1 text-white rounded-sm transition-all duration-300 ease-in-out focus:shadow-outline focus:outline-none"
                >
                  Login
                </button>
              )}
            </div>
          </div>
        )}
      </Transition>
```

Comment: what is `Transition` can you show the component or link to the npm package?

Comment: Shows us the `ref` object, thats what the error is about

Comment: You should include the rest of your code, not just the component's JSX.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can solve this by creating the ref variable using `useRef()` hook or `React.createRef()` and then pass the variable directly to the `ref` prop

```
const divRef = useRef()
```

Then you can use the ref

```
<div ref={divRef} > </div>
```

or if you are using class component

```
this.divRef = React.createRef()
```

then

```
<div ref={this.divRef} > </div>
```